# Does sort -um still guarantee uniqueness?

Tags: linux, bash

Sort -um assumes that two files are already unique and sorted and then merges them while making sure the output is still unique. But what if one of the files provided is not actually unique? Would the output still be unique or could it contain duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files don't need to be unique, just sorted. `-m` only requires that each file already be sorted. Duplicate lines are allowed.

```
$ cat 1.txt
a
b
b
b
c
c
$ cat 2.txt
a
a
a
b
c
c
$ sort -um 1.txt 2.txt
a
b
c
```